# Compare chosen date with filename using php

Tags: php

There are few thousands of file in a folder. I want to give the user to choose a date and show all the files based on chosen date.

File format is `bt_16-08-30_00_22_03.db`

Here is how I'm getting all the files

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dbfilepath) as $file) {
   if ($file->isFile()) {
     $thefilename = $file->getFilename();
     if (strripos($thefilename,".db")==true) {
       $thefiles[$countdirfiles] = $thefilename;
       $countdirfiles++;
     }
   }
 }
```

How can I find all the files with a specific **date** only?

> Note:
>   bt_16-08-30_00_22_03 -> 30th August, 2016 at 00:22:03

Comment: try to use `glob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my method.

Assign date to session (or any other). Make it similar to filename.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['onedate'])){
  $btfifiletocomp = 'bt_' . date('y-m-d', strtotime($_SESSION['onedate'])) . '';      
}
```

Now check if filename contains **$btfifiletocomp**

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dbfilepath) as $file) {
   if ($file->isFile()) {
     $thefilename = $file->getFilename();
     if (strripos($thefilename,".db")==true) {
       if (0 === strpos($thefilename, $btfifiletocomp)){
         $thefiles[$countdirfiles] = $thefilename;
         $countdirfiles++;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 solutions

check if your date is in the filename

```
$date = '16-08-30';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dbfilepath) as $file) {
   if ($file->isFile()) {
     $thefilename = $file->getFilename();
     if (strripos($thefilename,".db")==true && strpos($thefilename, $date) !== false) {
       $thefiles[] = $thefilename;
     }
   }
 }
```

Note that you don't need `$countdirfiles`

Or using glob you can use a regexp

```
$pattern = '*'.$date.'*.db';  // not sure about that regexp  
foreach (glob(pattern) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename \n";
}
```